# problem with kinect tutorial

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to kinect and ROS, and am using Ubuntu 10.10.
After following the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect and http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Getting%20Started, I still can not getting any point clouds from the kinect.

From the RVIZ, it says "no message received" for the TOPIC under pointCloud2.
Also, the following error in the console:

+++++++++++++++++

...

[Stream 70] Expected 1748 data bytes, but got 1908. Dropping...

[Stream 70] Expected 1748 data bytes, but got 1908. Dropping...

[kinect_driver-4] process has died [pid 30244, exit code -4].
log files: /home/blurpc2/.ros/log/93cd600e-4130-11e0-99b0-000e7faeafc1/kinect_driver-4*.log

+++++++++++++++++

What did I miss?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9210/problem-with-kinect-tutorial./) by [Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/193/qi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-25**:
Please edit your post and add the following facts.  How soon did it crash?  Immediately? When rviz was started?  What hardware are you running on? What's the contents of the log file called out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diamondback is definitely the way to go if you want to use the ni driver.  Cturtle has problems there.  The MIT hand_interaction demo works well with Diamondback, but you do have to get the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set up properly.

With regard to the question about pointCloud2, use
rostopic list
to see what is being published, then you will know if the topic is there.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried the [ni](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni) stack? As far as I know, if you are mainly looking for depth and camera information from the Kinect (in the form of a PointCloud or otherwise) the NI stack is the recommended way to go.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-26**:
I've removed the old kinect tutorial and tried to make the ni stack recommendation stronger.